Internet Information Services - .exe does not recognize actions in url (Delphi exe)
I am having a problem when invoking an .exe that is a WebService developed in Delphi.
The .exe has an action by default, and if I pass it actions, for example myexe.exe/actionExample then it should grab it, but the problem is that it doesn't grab it.
The exe was developed in Delphi XE7, and de IIS version is 10.
It is a server that was installed from scratch, but I have another server that is old and I was not involved in its configuration. The problem I'm telling you about works fine on the old server.
I was testing all afternoon and couldn't get anything working.
I tested filters, permissions, created rewrite rules, but nothing worked.
In fact, I compared it with the old server, and overall everything is the same. I don’t know if it’s some DLL or a separate installer.
Has anyone encountered this problem and can help me?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
